# How do I serve static files from express after manipulating one of the files?

Tags: node.js, express

I am using an express server and I want to serve js and css files on a path but I can't use express.static because I want to append something to js file depending on the request query param.

Any suggestion on how to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Well your file isn't a static file so you can't serve it with `express.static()`.  Instead, create a route for that single file and place this route before your static file handling.

```
app.get("/somefile", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let data = await fs.promises.readFile("somepath/somefile");
        // modify data here based on what's in req.query
        res.send(data);
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes but in this case, i won't be able to serve css file along with js. Currently, I am bundling my css along with js and then serving it like this. I was wondering if there is a way that I can serve both the files separately while editing js before serving. This is to reduce file size.

Comment: @Ekanshi - `express.static()` does not have that capability.  It could probably be massively hacked, but that would be more work and more code than what I've shown above.  `express.static()` should be used for static resources, not for dynamic content.  It's unclear to me why you continue to try to use `express.static()` for something it is not suited for when the alternative is simple.  If you have a bunch of files that want the same treatment, then you can generalize this solution to work for all of them.  Also, perhaps you should be using a template engine to render your files.

Comment: i am not using `express.static()`. I wrote css inline and am serving my file like you suggested.  I just wanted to know if there is a way to serve dynamic js and css files on one path in express.

Comment: @Ekanshi - What does "server dynamic js and css files on one path" mean?  You can have a completely separate route for `/xxxx/yyy` and `/xxxx/zzz`.  One could serve a dynamic resource, one could serve a static resource.  Of you can put your dynamic route handlers BEFORE your `express.static()` route and serve any dynamic files from the same directory as your static files.

Comment: @Ekanshi - This site works best if you show us your code and describe what problem you're having with that code.  That makes it a lot more likely that we can accurately understand exactly what your question is and can code an answer for you that precisely addresses your problem.  Generic questions without any code are often much harder to answer.

Comment: sure, thankyou. I will try to include code in my questions from next time. For this particular problem, I think it is just better to have different routes for diff files like you suggested. Thankyou :)